# select from 2 tables and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to select from data from 2 tables:

- users
- providers

If mail exist in users create only on providers, but if email does not exist create user and providers:

```
User.joins('LEFT JOIN providers on providers.user_id = users.id').where("users.email = '#{auth.info.email}' AND providers.provider = '#{auth.provider}' AND providers.uid = '#{auth.uid}'").first_or_create do |user|
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.uid = auth.uid
  user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
  user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
  if auth.info.nickname.nil?
    user.username = I18n.transliterate(auth.info.name.gsub(' ', '.')).downcase
  else
    user.username = auth.info.nickname
  end
end
```

I have this code but only create user record and provider is skip.

Comment: Did you check if the auth object is NIL?

Comment: No, should I do before join yes?

Comment: `first_or_create`  will only execute block is user does not exist.

Comment: And what sould I use?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself an answer. Feel free to improve

```
        user = where(email: auth.info.email).first_or_create do |user|
        user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
        user.email = auth.info.email
        if auth.info.nickname.nil?
                    user.username = I18n.transliterate(auth.info.name.gsub(' ', '.')).downcase
                else
                    user.username = auth.info.nickname
            end
      end

        Provider.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |pvd|
                pvd.provider = auth.provider
                pvd.uid = auth.uid
                pvd.user_id = user.id
            end

            return user
```